# Output a dict in python

Tags: python

Hi guys i'm struggling with these classes. 
this is what i have to do: `cours` stands for `course` and `etudiant` stands for `student`. I have to create a class Student that will do the following and i also have to use `repr`. so create object with student number and add courses

```
>>> d = Etudiant(12456)
>>> d.addCours('csi2520')
>>> d.addCours('csi2772')
>>> d.addCours('csi2510')
>>> d
12456:[ 'csi2520', 'csi2772', 'csi2510']
>>> d.cours('csi2510')
True
>>> d.cours('csi4900')
False
```

This is what i did but it's not working

```
class Etudiant:
    cours=[]
    def __init__(self, numero):
        self.numero=numero
        self.classe={self.numero:self.cours}
        repr(self.classe)
    def addCours(self, cours1):
        self.cours.insert(-1,cours1)
```

please keep it simple i'm a newbie

Comment: Not working how? What isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: This is what i get when i try to list the dictionary <__main__.Etudiant object at 0x000000000330BCC0>

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python

Comment: You should implement a `__repr__` method for your class. That function should output all the relevant information that your class contains (i.e. student number and course number list).

The linked SO talks about the difference between that and implementing a `__str__` method, but the implication was that you need one of those. `__str__` falls back on `__repr__` so if you only implement one, it'd be `__repr__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To alter how a Python object looks when it's printed, you need to implement a magic method called `__repr__` (short for representation). You also don't need to store the student number inside the `cours` variable:

```
class Etudiant(object):
    def __init__(self, numero):
        self.numero = numero
        self._cours = []
    def addCours(self, cours):
        self._cours.append(cours)
    def cours(self, cours):
        return cours in self._cours
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(self.numero, self._cours)
```

Testing:

```
>>> d = Etudiant(12456)
>>> d.addCours('csi2520')
>>> d.addCours('csi2772')
>>> d.addCours('csi2510')
>>> d
12456: ['csi2520', 'csi2772', 'csi2510']
>>> d.cours('csi2510')
True
>>> d.cours('csi4900')
False
```